# How do I lower the temperature of an electric boiler in France/Europe?

Tags: insulation, water-heater, temperature

My electric boiler is delivering VERY hot water: my hands are often burned when I forget to mix it with normal-tempered water.

Do you think there is a way I can make the boiler heating the water something like a maximum of 40 degree celsius ? on top of that it takes more energy to heat that water (even if any boiler has top-notch insulation).

The manufacturer is Olympic: 861154. 1200W, 100L, 230V

Comment: Many dishwashing detergents depend on really hot water to work well. If your dishwasher can heat the water, fine, but if not, you may notice dirtier dishes if you turn down the temp.

Answer (score 1):

For most boilers the desired temperature is user-configurable. I suggest looking in the manual to find the specific instructions for your model (I searched, but could not find an online copy of the manual for your model).

Another solution would be to change the plumbing to mix in an amount of cold water. It's best to do this near to the output of your boiler.